# Python program for json files

Tags: python-3.x

i want to search a particular keyword in a .json file and print 10 lines above and below the line in which the searched keyword is present.
Note - the keyword might be present more than once in the file.

So far i have made this -

```
with open('loggy.json', 'r') as f:
    last_lines = deque(maxlen=5)
    for ln, line in enumerate(f):
        if "out_of_memory" in line:
            print(ln)
            sys.stdout.writelines(chain(last_lines, [line], islice(f, 5)))
            last_lines.append(line)
            print("Next Error")
    print("No More Errors")
```

Problem with this is - the number of times it prints the keyword containing line is equal to that number of times the keyword has been found.
it is only printing 5 lines below it, whereas i want it to print five lines above it as well.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to actually load the data using `json.load` (the `json` module is part of the standard library) and then work with that?

Comment: *lines* don't necessarily make much sense for json files. It could all be on *one line* for instance. Maybe you could explain *why* you think showing this would be useful? (Seeing elements in a list etc...)

Comment: i get json files of real large size, and i have need to check for these kind of keywords to identify somethings ,So for that i need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the json file was misused to store really a lot of information, then
processing on-the-fly may be better. In the case, keep the history lines
say in the list that is shortened if it grows above a given limit. 
Then use a counter that indicates how many lines must be displayed after
observing a problem:

```
#!python3

def print_around_pattern(pattern, fname, numlines=10):
    """Prints the lines with the pattern from the fname text file.

    The pattern is a string, numline is the number of lines printed before
    and after the line with the pattern (with default value 10).
    """

    history = []
    cnt = 0
    with open(fname, encoding='utf8') as fin:
        for n, line in enumerate(fin):
            history.append(line)            # append the line
            history = history[-numlines-1:] # keep only the tail, including last line
            if pattern in line:
                # Print the separator and the history lines including the pattern line.
                print('\n{!r} at the line {} ----------------------------'.format(
                         pattern, n+1))
                for h in history:
                    print('{:03d}: {}'.format(n-numlines, h), end='')
                cnt = numlines              # set the counter for the next lines        
            elif cnt > 0:
                # The counter indicates we want to see this line.
                print('{:03d}: {}'.format(n+1, line), end='')
                cnt -= 1                    # decrement the counter


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_around_pattern('out_of_memory', 'loggy.json')
    ##print_around_pattern('out_of_memory', 'loggy.json', 3)  # three lines before and after
```

Comment: with the above code, every alternative error displayed has only above 5 lines #pepr. and the rest is working fine.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed, and enhanced. Now you can call the function with other patterns, and you can also pass a different number of context lines instead of the default 10.